How can I view org-headings that have notes added to the LOGBOOK drawer in the last 48 hours?
If I log a note to the LOGBOOK drawer, using org-add-note, how can I find them again?
I want to list the org-headings that have notes added to them in the last 48 hours.
I tried this, but this doesn't return anything:
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("ln" "Notes added in the last 48 hours"
               tags "+NOTE={.+48h}"
               ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Notes added in the last 48 hours")
                (org-tags-match-list-sublevels nil))))



...  tags "+NOTE={.+48h}" ... - did you find this documented somewhere or is it a shot in the dark? AFAICT, this has no chance of working the way you expect: it searches for entries that have a NOTE property whose value matches the regexp .+48h. Adding a note does not add any such property; moreover the note has the form - Note taken on [2024-11-25 Mon 12:20] \\   Some note so there is no way it can match the regexp. You'll need to write your own function to implement the search criteria you describe.

Maybe an easier way is to use org-after-note-stored-hook to add such a property (with the current date as value). Then you can use a match expression like "+NOTE>=\"<-2d>\"". Not sure if you can do "date and time" calculations like this, so you may not get your wish for "48hrs": instead, depending on what time of the day you ask the question, you may get positive answers for between 48 hours (if you ask shortly after midnight at the start of the day) to 72 hours (if you ask just before midnight at the end of the day).

Here is an implementation along the lines of my second comment below the question: we make org-add-note add (or modify) a property NOTE_DATE giving it the current date and time as value: if multiple notes are added, the property stores the latest date and time that a note was added.
We first write a function that adds or modifies the property[1]:
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun ndk/add-note-date-property ()
    (org-entry-put nil
                   "NOTE_DATE"
                   (org-format-timestamp
                    (org-timestamp-from-time
                     (time-convert (current-time) 'list) 'with-time)
                    "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M]")))

#+end_src


We then add it to the hook `org-after-note-stored-hook:
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
(add-hook 'org-after-note-stored-hook #'ndk/add-note-date-property)
#+end_src


Now when we add a note with C-c C-z, the property is added or modified appropriately[2]:
...
** hook test 1
:PROPERTIES:
:NOTE_DATE: <2024-11-28 02:02>
:END:
:LOGBOOK:
- Note taken on [2024-11-28 Thu 02:02] \\
  Final note
- Note taken on [2024-11-28 Thu 00:56] \\
  third note
- Note taken on [2024-11-28 Thu 00:56] \\
  some other note
- Note taken on [2024-11-28 Thu 00:35] \\
  some note
:END:

...



We can then use a tags/property search (see Matching Tags and Properties in the manual) to search for the property and check that its value is within the last two days:
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("ln" "Notes added in the last 48 hours"
               tags "+NOTE_DATE>=\"<-2d>\""
               ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Notes added in the last 48 hours")
                (org-tags-match-list-sublevels nil))))

#+end_src


This search only uses the date part, not the time, so it finds headlines with "recent" notes added, where "recent" is defined as "newer than 48-72 hours ago": if I ask the question on 2024-11-28, then I will get headlines with notes added on 2024-11-26 and later, but the time is not taken into account at all, so if the note was added early on the 26th and I asked late on the 28th, it will find the note.
There may be a search that takes time into account, but if so, I don't know it.

Footnotes:
[1] Originally the function used angle brackets in the value of the property, making the time stamp look like an active timestamp. That caused the agenda to interpret it as active timestamp (although, strictly speaking, the value of a property should be an uninterpreted string - see Org Syntax), so the item got added to the agenda. Replacing the angle brackets with square brackets makes it look like an inactive timestamp (so the agenda ignores it), but the subsequent search still works.
[2] This assumes that org-log-into-drawer is set to t, either globally, through a file-local variable, or through a #+STARTUP: logdrawer setting in the file.

Wow, that's a great answer;). It also works. Thanks a super bunch.

Hmm, I'm not sure what's happening here, but this shows up in my org-agenda as a scheduled event

Yes, I was thinking about that last night. I think that the timestamp in the property looks like an active timestamp and the agenda code uses a regexp for matching so it interprets it as an active time stamp instead of skipping it (syntactically, it's just a string, so it should, strictly speaking, just skip it). I'll try to make it look like an inactive time stamp (change the angle brackets to square brackets in the hook function) but I'm not sure whether the matching will still work. Stay tuned.

See the edited function that uses square brackets. It seems to work: the timestamp looks inactive and the agenda ignores it, but the search still works as expected.

Thank you. Yes, seems to work;). I'll keep testing, cause I imagine using this function a lot;)
